# Set WPF Image Source from a Hyper Link (from Internet)

Tags: c#, wpf, image, hyperlink

I try to set WPF image source from an Internet link. How can I do this?
I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
Image image1 = new Image();
BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
bi3.BeginInit();
bi3.UriSource = new Uri("link" + textBox2.Text + ".png", UriKind.Relative);
bi3.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi3.EndInit();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prepending `"link"` to the URL is certainly incorrect. Just make sure that you type the full path of your image into your textbox.

```
// For example, type the following address into your text box:
textBox2.Text = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ccac9a107581b343e832a2b040278b98?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG";

bi3.UriSource = new Uri(textBox2.Text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

Comment: Glad to have helped! Don’t forget to prepend your images with `"http://"`; it helps .NET to know the scheme of your URL.

Comment: How can I know if the link exists? For example if I type "http://ahsdjaksdjahk.png", it doesn't give me an error.

Comment: I’m not sure… One way would be to attempt to download the link using a `WebClient` and check the response code, but I assume there are better ways.